# Selenium null pointer exception, when trying to use constructor

Tags: java, pointers, exception, selenium, null

I created a class which has page objects defined in it. Then I am trying to use that class in a test class by using a constructor. However when I run the test class using JUnit I am getting a `NullPointerException` error.

**Page_Objects Class:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Page_Objects {

    private WebDriver driver;

    WebElement Username = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
    // ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
    WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    WebElement Login_Button = driver.findElement(By.id("Login"));
    WebElement Logout_Button = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout"));

}
```

**Test Class:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Salesforce_Test {
  private WebDriver driver1;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  Page_Objects pageobjects = new Page_Objects();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "some url for testing/";
    driver1.navigate().to(baseUrl);
    driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void Login_Logout() throws Exception {

    pageobjects.Username.sendKeys("someusername");

    // ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
    pageobjects.Password.sendKeys("somepassword");

    pageobjects.Login_Button.click();

    pageobjects.Logout_Button.click();

  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver1.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver1.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver1.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver1.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**When I run the above class I get a null pointer exception.**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Page_Objects.<init>(Page_Objects.java:20)
    at Salesforce_Test.<init>(Salesforce_Test.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here. First is that the `Page_Objects` class is called before you initiated the driver. That's why when you're calling
`Page_Objects pageobjects = new Page_Objects();` 
you're getting a `NullPointerException`.
So you want to initiate the `Page_Objects` after you've initiated the driver.
Second, you need to pass it the instance of the driver you've initiated, because right now it has its own Private driver which isn't initiated and therefore it's null.
So in short:

- Initiate `Page_Objects` after you've initiated driver (after the `driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();` line)
- Call it with the driver you've initiated: `Page_Objects pageobjects = new Page_Objects(driver1 );`

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to have worked. I had to create some methods in the Page_Objects class first.